# GIS Data for Illinois Electric Distribution lines and Substations

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, energy

I am looking for the Ameren and ComED's distribution lines and distribution substations. They are the 2 largest electrical utilities in Illinois. I know the HLIFD data has Transmission lines and transmission substations, but these are 2 different types of systems.

Comment: Dumb question: have you contacted the companies themselves? The State of Illinois may have some information here as well.

Comment: @BarryCarter sorry for the lack of clarification. I have contacted each company with no response. The state itself has no Utility data on its open data site or on its clearinghouse site.

Answer (score 2):

[Geoplatform.gov](https://www.geoplatform.gov/) has a Transmission Lines layer available as an ESRI REST Feature Service.

You can view it on ArcGIS online [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https://services1.arcgis.com/Hp6G80Pky0om7QvQ/ArcGIS/rest/services/Electric_Power_Transmission_Lines/FeatureServer&source=sd)

View the metadata or download it as an XML file [here](https://oe.geoplatform.gov/view/9fd486525b5f4d44a36273b7533cb512)

Or use the [service URL](https://services1.arcgis.com/Hp6G80Pky0om7QvQ/arcgis/rest/services/Electric_Power_Transmission_Lines/FeatureServer) to load it into a GIS program.

[Here's GeoJSON version exported from ESRI](https://bowdenweb.com/a/data/usa-transmission-lines.geojson)
Sorry for personal URL, but gist.github.com chokes on the size of it.

Comment: why would you edit the most valid answer in the selection?